# Resolving @use imports from node_modules with the sass node command line?

Tags: css, node.js, npm, sass

I'm trying to play around with the SASS generated by [material web components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web).

I create a new node project like this:

```
mkdir sassplayground
```

And initialize it with dependencies:

```
cd sassplayground
npm i @material/button
npm i @material/theme
```

If we run `sass --watch test.scss:test.css` on on `test.scss` with these contents:

```
@use 'sass:map';
@use '@material/button/button' as mdc-button;
```

We get this error:

```
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
2 │ @use '@material/button/button' as mdc-button;
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  test.scss 2:1  root stylesheet
```

And if we fix it by prefixing with `node_modules` like this:

```
@use 'sass:map';
@use 'node_modules/@material/button/button' as mdc-button;
```

We get a transitive dependency error like this:

```
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
   ╷
26 │ @use '@material/feature-targeting/feature-targeting';
```

How to we resolve SASS dependencies from `node_modules`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK this works:

```
sass --watch test.scss:test.css --load-path=node_modules
```